# How to access this part of the object

Tags: php, object, curl

I am using curl to POST data to a json file on a drupal server. I have that working and it returns a string like so:

```
{
  "result":"success",
  "user":{
    "uid":"15",
    "theme":"",
    "signature":"",
    "signature_format":"plain_text",
    "created":"1335991710",
    "access":"1363715947",
    "login":1363716262,
    "status":"1",
    "timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
    "language":"",
    "picture":"0",
    "data":false,
    "uuid":"89847add-54c8-c4b4-5dfc-bddc96e99919",
    "roles":{
      "2":"authenticated user",
      "4":"dOP staff"
    },
    "field_user_client":{
      "und":[
        {
          "nid":"17740"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get at the `result` part of the json string. I've tried casting the string as an object but that didn't work. I've tried the following:

```
<?php
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
echo $curlResult->result; //fails
?>
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: use `json_decode` on the return data first

Comment: I had also tried `$curlResult = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));` so I was close. It looks like @WackyWalrus solution may work

Comment: that question marked as a duplicate is not true by the way. That marked answer doesn't even answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is CURL really required? This should works fine:

```
<?
$resArray = json_decode($ch, true);
$result = $resArray['result'];
?>
```

Comment: It is required as the server is on another domain

Comment: you can use CURL to retrive JSON string and json_decode() to parse it into an object or array

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to do. I have retrieved the JSON string, now I need to parse it into an object or array

Comment: ah, I was missing the `true` part of the `json_decode`..this works, thank you!

Comment: yes, second param allows you to get json data back as an object either an array. good luck!

Comment: yep, just looked that up in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Curl, but that looks like a JSON array. You might need to use the php function [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Try something like:

```
<?php
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
$array = json_decode($curlResult->result);
echo $array->result;
?>
```

There's also [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) if you need to put the array back into JSON.

Comment: I am getting this error in php: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Sorry, I see you already got your answer but I think it would be $array['result'] rather than $array->result